# jquery select alerts the wrong drop-down menu option value for on-change js behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors

I have Js array that holds the values of dynamic menu. The option values of menu changes with the ID of event.

There is a jQuery pop-up window which contains the form. After loading the window, the menu options show up but the jquery does not alert the right selected value...it always shows the first item in the select options

Go to the below link and click on "Join Event" buttons for event id=130131CHcbd and 150724CH5f1 where you see that no what event date you pick, it alerts the same date...

http://www.weg2g.com/application/abovezest/personal_networking.php

I've basic knowledge of JS, so any advice or help to solve this issue...

```html
<script> 
var jArray= {"150724CH5f1":"<option value=\"2017-01-27\" id=\"1\"> Fri Jan 27th 2017<\/option>  <option value=\"2017-02-03\" id=\"2\"> Fri Feb 3rd 2017<\/option>  <option value=\"2017-02-10\" id=\"3\"> Fri Feb 10th 2017<\/option>  <option value=\"2017-02-17\" id=\"4\"> Fri Feb 17th 2017<\/option>  <option value=\"2017-02-24\" id=\"5\"> Fri Feb 24th 2017<\/option>","130131CHcbd":"<option value=\"2017-01-28\" id=\"1\"> Sat Jan 28th 2017<\/option>  <option value=\"2017-02-04\" id=\"2\"> Sat Feb 4th 2017<\/option>  <option value=\"2017-02-11\" id=\"3\"> Sat Feb 11th 2017<\/option>  <option value=\"2017-02-18\" id=\"4\"> Sat Feb 18th 2017<\/option>  <option value=\"2017-02-25\" id=\"5\"> Sat Feb 25th 2017<\/option>"}; //get all 
function bind_event_dates(v,type)
{ 
 //alert(jArray[v]);
 var w=jArray[v];
 //var y="'"+v+"'";
 
  if (type==3)
 {
 var str1='<select name="edate" id="edate_bn_d" onchange="check_e_date(3);" required>';
 } //
 
 
 //append the other parts
 var str2=str1.concat(w);
 var str3='</select>';
 var kk=str2.concat(str3);
 
 //alert(rrr);
 $("#load_dates3").html(kk);
 
}//end of binding event dates
//--------------------------------------
  function check_e_date(a)
{
   if (a==3)
  
  {
  var wanted=$("#edate_bn_d").val();
          //always select the first option of select menue
  alert(wanted);
  $("#bn_roomatte").val(wanted)
  }
  


}//end of check event date function
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
//
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML as well.

Comment: Go to the below link and click on "Join Event" buttons for event id=130131CHcbd and 150724CH5f1 where you can use inspect element to see html codes

http://www.weg2g.com/application/abovezest/personal_networking.php

Answer (score 0):

I have edit code javascript. It has working.

> 

```js
var jArray= {"150724CH5f1":"<option value=\"2017-01-27\" id=\"1\"> Fri Jan 27th 2017<\/option>  <option value=\"2017-02-03\" id=\"2\"> Fri Feb 3rd 2017<\/option>  <option value=\"2017-02-10\" id=\"3\"> Fri Feb 10th 2017<\/option>  <option value=\"2017-02-17\" id=\"4\"> Fri Feb 17th 2017<\/option>  <option value=\"2017-02-24\" id=\"5\"> Fri Feb 24th 2017<\/option>","130131CHcbd":"<option value=\"2017-01-28\" id=\"1\"> Sat Jan 28th 2017<\/option>  <option value=\"2017-02-04\" id=\"2\"> Sat Feb 4th 2017<\/option>  <option value=\"2017-02-11\" id=\"3\"> Sat Feb 11th 2017<\/option>  <option value=\"2017-02-18\" id=\"4\"> Sat Feb 18th 2017<\/option>  <option value=\"2017-02-25\" id=\"5\"> Sat Feb 25th 2017<\/option>"}; //get all 
function bind_event_dates(v,type)
{ 
 //alert(jArray[v]);
 var w=jArray[v];
 //var y="'"+v+"'";
 
  if (type==3)
 {
 var str1='<select name="edate" id="edate_bn_d" onchange="check_e_date(3);" required>';
 } //
 
 
 //append the other parts
 var str2=str1.concat(w);
 var str3='</select>';
 var kk=str2.concat(str3);
 
 //alert(rrr);
 $("#load_dates3").html(kk);
 
}//end of binding event dates
//--------------------------------------
  function check_e_date(a)
{
     if (a==3)  
  {
  var wanted=$("#edate_bn_d").val();
          //always select the first option of select menue
  alert(wanted);
  $("#bn_roomatte").val(wanted)
  }
  


}//end of check event date function
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
//
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">      
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Domoos mobile</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"> 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="bind_event_dates('150724CH5f1',3);">
 <div id="load_dates3">
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You added on page load behavior. However, when a use click on a button the jQuery window opens, then menu options are populated. The options are populated perfectly; however, it does select the right value. Did you see the link to the site where alert gives the wrong values..

Comment: As a note, it works perfect on event detail page where there is no jArray and the form options are populated by php